# How do I close an OracleConnection in .NET

Tags: oracle, database-connection, dispose, using

Say I have these two objects:

```
OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);  
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sql, connection);
```

To close the connection or Oracle, do I have to call command.Dispose(), connection.Dispose(), or both?

Is this good enough:

```
using(connection)  
{
    OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    // whatever...
}
```

Answer (score 17):

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
        }
    }
}
```

If it implements IDisposable, and if you create it, then put it in a using block.

Comment: Are the inner usings actually needed, or is the one for 'connection' good enough?

Comment: You need to dispose of all your IDisposable objects, so each using is needed. If you don't you will only dispose of the connection, and the children will be left.

Comment: Granted for database connections (and for IDiposable in general), but it won't do with cascading input/output streams where disposing a parent disposes the child.

Comment: Does `OracleConnection` and `OracleCommand ` implement IDisposable?

Comment: @Giorgi: yes, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.aspx

Comment: @JohnSaunders: hmm I seemed to look at those links, but could not find where they specifically mention that it implements IDisposable

Comment: @Giorgi: check the base classes in both cases.

Comment: Don't you have to do connection.open() explicitly? And the "using" takes care of closing the connection ?

Comment: @try: Yes, but the question is focused on IDisposable, so that detail is omitted.

Answer (score 7):

Both answers are pretty much on target. You almost always want to call .Dispose() on any IDisposeable object. By wrapping in a "using" you tell the compiler to always implement a try/finialy block for you.

1 point of note, if you want to avoid the nesting, you can write the same code like this:

```
 using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
 using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sql, connection))
 using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // do something here
    }
```

Comment: you *can* write the code like that, but IMHO you should **never**  write it like that.

Comment: Can you give specifics why? I work by myself a lot, ( not by choice ), so I am always looking for outside feedback.

Comment: Agreed.  At first glance would someone understand what object is encapsulated in another.  Use more parentheses and indentation.

Comment: @wonea New way of doing things is no brackets whatsoever but using declarations
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using

Answer (score 3):

This is good enough. using statement will wrap the dispose statement, so even if the exception is thrown, you are safe, it's my preferred way to dispose the resource.

```
using(OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);    )  
{
   //Create a command object 
    using(OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sql, connection))
    {
      using(OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
      }

    }
    // whatever...
}
```

I think by use "using", you are ask the compiler to inject a try ... finally block , and in finally block, it will close the disposable object for you.

Answer (score 3):

`using` will ensure your connection is closed. You could also pass in `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` to your command's `ExecuteReader` method to close it before `Dispose` is called.